# Bash variable containing file wildcard

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable containing wildarded file descriptors:

```
FORMATS='*.mobi *.pdf *.txt *.epub *.lit'
```

It gets expanded with the appropriate files if I write

```
echo $FORMATS
```

and retains its string value if i quote it

```
echo "$FORMATS"
```

Now, I need to manipulate it as a string and I do this.

```
SUBST=`echo "$FORMATS" | sed "s/$1//"`
```

The problem is that within `` the files get expanded anyway. How to prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: Really? Have you tried `echo "$SUBST"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't get expanded!

What you are probably doing is using `SUBST` without quotes (eg: `echo $SUBST`) and then it gets expanded... use `"$SUBST"`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
cd /tmp/formats
touch a.mobi b.pdf c.txt e.epub f.lit
a='*.mobi *.pdf *.txt *.epub *.lit'
echo "$a"
*.mobi *.pdf *.txt *.epub *.lit
echo $a  
a.mobi b.pdf c.txt e.epub f.lit
b=pdf
c=$(echo "${a/\*.$b}")
echo "$c"
*.mobi  *.txt *.epub *.lit
echo $c  
a.mobi c.txt e.epub f.lit
```

Answer (score 0):

without seeing more of your code I can only guess that maybe you want to do something like this:

:this is shell only - no other tools needed

```
for FILE in *.mobi *.pdf *.txt *.epub *.lit ; do
    case "$FILE" in
        "*.mobi"|"*.pdf"|"*.txt"|"*.epub"|"*.lit")continue;;
        *)echo "${FILE//$1/}";;
    esac
done
```

presumably you would mv or cp the file to the new file name???