# bash pattern with asterisk

Tags: bash, glob

I have the following simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -fx 
ls *sh
```

The problem is that bash add a quote to the pattern and I get wrong output.

```
+ ls '*sh'
ls: cannot access *sh: No such file or directory
```

How can I change this behavior?

The output of `ls *sh` from the terminal is:

```
$ls *sh 
a.bash  a.sh  b.sh
```

I tried to add quotes according to this post - "[Bash variable containing file wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053629/bash-variable-containing-file-wildcard)" 
without success

Comment: never use ls in your scripts. But if you want to use it like ls *.sh

Comment: `-x` is adding the quotes because that is what it does. That's not actually in what is being run. Your issue is almost certainly a path one. Especially if you are trying to run this from `cron` or a desktop environment menu/shortcut.

Comment: hey so why i get the "No such file or directory" instead of the real output? ( i run the script from the terminal in the same directory that  i do "ls" and it's not shortcut...)

Comment: @BallPython You can use `ls` in a script. You just shouldn't try to parse its output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That because you're disabling [`pathname expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-pathname-expansion) with the [`-f`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) option.

```
#!/bin/bash -fx
```

From man:

```
-f
    Disable filename expansion (globbing).
```